# On Android, how long do I have to respond (and to what?) before being killed?

Tags: android, timeout

On Android, it is my understanding that if you don't respond to certain events from the operating system within some timeout, it will deem your application to have hung and prompt the user to kill it.

So my first question is: What, *specifically*, are those things? I would guess things like `Activity.onPause`, `View.onTouchEvent`, `SurfaceHolder.Callback.surfaceCreated`, etc? Is there a list? Or is it simply every single callback that comes from the OS?

(Or is it perhaps implemented as how often some thread message queue is internally polled? Details?)

And my second question is: How long is the timeout?

Comment: You want to make sure to not even get close to the 5s timeout. Anything in the range of 1s is getting quite annoying, if it occurs frequently.

Comment: @sstn: Does it block the whole Android UI? Or just your own application?

Comment: Probably everything - at least in cases of onPause() etc. Not sure about simple button clicks.

Comment: @SYLARRR: I was hoping to get more details about how the 5-second time-out is implemented. But ok.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no response in 5 seconds, user gets the "app is not responding screen". As I see it, you have to respond anything running on the main thread in 5 seconds, otherwise the user will be prompted to kill your app.

> Even worse, if the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5 seconds currently) the user is presented with the infamous "application not responding" (ANR) dialog.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html)

Comment: Is there anyway to change timeout of the ANR programatically ?

Comment: No because it is a design choice to prevent bad programming and to prevent user irritability.